# How to compile the AndEngine sources?

Tags: java, android, andengine

In this post:
http://www.andengine.org/forums/post17375.html#p17375
Nicolas Gramlich suggest try to compile the AndEngine sources. Where I can get AndEngine GLES1 sources or how i can do this another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is very difficult to google "andengine sources"...

http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/checkout

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Comment: @sherman On GitHub, just change which branch you are browsing - GLES1 is on branch "master".

Comment: Do you guys know how difficult it is to get started with AndEngine. Its soo poorly documented. Everything I ever downloaded, cloned is broken. Jar's are not available for download in places where they are suppose to be. The Blog is completely unreadable. So questions on AndEngine cant just be voted down. Help should be share. AndEngine is a good engine to use, but please dont underestimate the effort needed to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Look [how use andengine source](http://andreylunevich.blogspot.com/2012/02/andengine-2.html)