# How to compile AndEngine? 1300+ Errors?

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479139/how-to-compile-the-andengine-sources), but I have the source and I'm having so many problems compiling it.

I've downloaded the latest version from the GLES2 branch, commit 7b6e842498. I've imported it into Eclipse. My hope was I could immediately start using it, but instead I get over 1300 errors of some of the stupidest crap. Stuff like "method must override a superclass method" and the superclass has the same method, or " cannot be resolved or is not a field" on an enum but is definitely a field, I checked it myself and intellisense actually offers that field as a choice. I've tried setting it for Android versions 2.1 and 4.0 with no noticeable differences. I've tried right clicking it and selecting Android Tools > Fix Project Properties which did nothing. I'm really annoyed with this because at one point about a month ago it was working, but I lost it since then.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple in some config file but can't find it. I have similar problems with the master branch of AndEngine, but I want the GLES 2 version anyway. I'm running Windows 7 x64 and I have the latest Eclipse, JDK, ADT, and SDKs installed and running just fine. I just formatted a few days ago so they're all brand new. What am I missing?

Comment: Try going to Properties -> Java Compiler and using 1.5 or 1.6

Comment: @RaghavSood, if that fixes it... Gah, I'm really appreciative, but upset with myself. Submit that as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you use a different version of the JDK to compile the project than the one it was written on. It can be fixed by manually choosing the compiler by right clicking, going to Properties -> Java Compiler and using either 1.5 or 1.6, depending on which one was already in use.

Comment: For the record, 1.5 was selected for me and moving up to 1.6 fixed it.